# When I import the formsmodule in angular my button seems to not working after that

Tags: javascript, angular

When I imported this "import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';"  on my angular project. it seems that my button is not working anymore. if I click on it there's nothing.

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is My Home HTML
the button class is btn

```
<div class="container color-dark">
    <div class="col">
        <p>Add you Bucket List</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <p>Your Bucket List ({{ itemCount }})</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container color-light">
    <div class="col">
        <p>Use this form to add a new Bucket List!</p>

        <form>
            <input type="text" class="txt" name="item" placeholder="Life Goal.." [(ngModel)]="goalText">
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Add Item" (click)="addItem()">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <p class="life.container">
            I want to climb a mountain.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is My home.compenent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  itemCount: number;
  btnText: string = 'Add an Item';
  goalText: string = 'My First Life Goal';
  goals = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemCount = this.goals.length;
  }

  additem(){
    this.goals.push(this.goalText);
    this.goalText = '';
    this.itemCount = this.goals.length;
  }

}
```

I tried searching it on google but nothing pops up or am I just looking at the wrong side of the code. if you have an idea or tips that can help me solve this, I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in home.components.ts correct the function name **from additem() to** **addItem()** it will work . capital I should be used that's why it's not working